# Calculate statuses from the object and display the results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please tell me how you can calculate the number of statuses from an object and display the results in `countStatus`?

```
var objs = {
  "Name A": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "status": "allow"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "status": "new"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "status": "new"
    }
  ],
  "Name B": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "status": "new"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, list) in objs">
  {{key}}
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
     {{item.status}} : {{countStatus}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
Name A
allow : 1
new : 2

Name B
new : 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method. The code below shows how to create your required result.

```js
const objs = {
  'Name A': [
    {
      id: 3,
      status: 'allow',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      status: 'new',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      status: 'new',
    },
  ],
  'Name B': [
    {
      id: 7,
      status: 'new',
    },
  ],
};

const ret = Object.keys(objs).map((x) => {
  return {
    [x]: Object.values(objs[x]).reduce((prev, c) => {
      const p = prev;
      p[c.status] = p[c.status] || 0;
      p[c.status] += 1;
      return p;
    }, {}),
  };
});
console.log(ret);
```

Print ret like below in Angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ret">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
    {{key}} 
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I output this to the form?
`<div ng-repeat="(key, list) in objs">
  {{key}}
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
     {{item.status}} : {{countStatus}}
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: @j.ss check the below code how to print and add `ret` to your scope.